# Does using the trim force command disable TRIM on my apple SSD

Tags: high-sierra

I have heard about this called `trimforce enable` which enables TRIM on third party SSDs. But I have an original apple ssd which has trim enabled by default. I ran the command. But then I read an article saying that running such a command will allow unsigned kexts. So I am thinking of disabling it. But I have a question if I run `trimforce disable` will it disable TRIM on my original Apple SSD?

Thanks

Comment: I think you may need to provide citations - because it sounds like someone has got their wires crossed somewhere.

Comment: @Tetsujin I read the article at https://randomnerds.com/execute-sudo-trimforce-enable-to-keep-your-ssd-healthy/

Comment: That doesn't mention unsigned kexts at all - which is the part I was querying.